# Solve $2(x^3y-y^3)y'=3(x^5+x^4y^4)$ using $x=u^p$ and $y=v^q$ for some chosen $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $2(x^3y-y^3)y'=3(x^5+x^4y^4)$ using $x=u^p$ and $y=v^q$ for some chosen $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$

I need help solving this ODE. I applied the substitution and did some algebra, but I couldn't proceed further. This is what I got:

$$y' = \frac{3x^5+3x^4y^4}{2x^3y-2y^3}$$
$$\frac{dv}{du} \cdot \frac{qv^{q-1}}{pu^{p-1}} = \frac{3u^{4p}(u^p+v^{4q})}{2v^q(u^{3p}-v^{2q})}$$

I know that this substitution should bring the ODE to an homogeneous one, but I can't find the way to perform the reduction. Its possible to solve this ODE with this substitution?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant. I edited for clarification. Sorry.

Comment: @JCAA, I suspect the problem is that Rodrigo doesn't see what $p,q$ to choose to get the problem into an easily solvable form.

Comment: Exactly, that's my principal doubt.

Comment: Are you sure the DE is correct ?